# New smart folder renamed "All My Files" folder. How to revert?

Tags: macos, finder, mojave, smart-folders

I created a new Smart Folder with the `Kind` is `Document` filter. I then sorted by `Date Last Opened` and saved the search as `Recents`.

It seems like doing so has overwritten the default "All My Files" folder:

[image: All My Files is now called Recents]

**Q: How do I revert this?**

---

It looks like the smart folder distributed with macOS is located at `/System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app/Contents/Resources/MyLibraries/myDocuments.cannedSearch`.

In Finder it's shown as `Recents`, even though the file on disk is called `myDocuments.cannedSearch`.

I can't rename this through Finder:

[image: Can't rename saved search through finder]

Opening `myDocuments.cannedSearch` in TextMate allows me to view the `.strings` files, which contain the `CFBundleDisplayName` key with `"Recents"` as the value:

[image: InfoPlist.strings English file]

It looks like macOS has also translated this:

[[image: InfoPlist.strings Dutch file[4]]

I don't really know where to look now to make this change in a way that won't break Finder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not tag an OS version, but MacOS Mojave ships by default with a Recents folder in the Finder sidebar and Go menu. There is by default no All My Files folder now. You have not overwritten anything.

(Or else, you overwrote mine too)

Comment: Oh! I removed "All My Files" from the sidebar when it first got introduced so I guess I just didn't realise "Recents" was a Thing and happened to create the same search with the same name. TIL!

Comment: It disappeared with High Sierra, replaced by Recents. [I don't use either so I hadn't noticed until now ;-) https://www.macworld.com/article/3262989/what-happened-to-the-all-my-files-feature-in-macos-high-sierra.html